# Selection of radio group button with tag, using bindings

Tags: cocoa, binding, tags, radio-button, nsdate

I am implementing a custom date range selector. The "from" part looks as follows:
[image]

A "to" section looks similar. When I select an end-date that is earlier than the starting date, I want to automatically switch the end date radiogroup to option 1 ("Custom") and put the "From" date in the calendar picker.

I have bound the starting and ending `NSDate` objects to the date pickers, and the tag values to the radio groups. I do not understand why the following does not result in a visible selection of the first button:

`[self setFromTag:1]`

Usually, the user still has a radio button pressed (not sure if that matters). Any help greatly appreciated!